# Confusion about binding a radio button to a model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC.  I'm trying to build a small website for people to pick winners in NFL games.  I am confused on how to translate what a user picks in the view to the data in my database.  I am using MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6.

I want the view to list each game, displaying the home team and the away team.  Next to each team there is a radio button.  The user selects the radio button next to each selection, and then clicks a Submit button.  For each game, I want to read which of the two radio buttons has been selected, and then write the name of the related team to a database table for Picks.  The database is already built and I can't change it.

So I have a model for Picks (id, week_number, game1, game2, etc).  I have a model for Schedule, which is all of the NFL games this season (id, week_number, game_number, home, away).  I have the basic controller from scaffolding it out, and I am trying to create a ViewModel to combine the two models for my what my view needs.

What I do not know how to do is add a radio button so that it is tied to the team name it is next to, so that when I submit it will be determined if that button is checked, and if so, to write that team name to the database.  Am I supposed to make 32 boolean properties for each radio button and then if it is checked look up the team name in a list of all the games?  It seems like this should be much easier, but I am stumped with the whole MVC structure.

Also, is this supposed to happen in the controller, and not the view model?  How do I access which radio button is selected?

**UPDATE**

I followed the suggestions here as best I could, and I am closer.  But the problem now is that all of the radio buttons on the page are in one radio button group - that is, only one button can be selected.  I want to have each row in the table be a group, so that ultimately there will be 16 buttons selected.  Here are the models and view I am using:

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTeam { get; set; }

    public GameViewModel()
    {
        AwayTeam = string.Empty;
        HomeTeam = string.Empty;
        SelectedTeam = string.Empty;
    }

    public GameViewModel(string away, string home)
    {
        AwayTeam = away;
        HomeTeam = home;
        SelectedTeam = string.Empty;
    }
}


public class WeeklyPicksViewModel
{
    private NFLEntities db = new NFLEntities();

    public int MNFscore { get; set; }
    public List<GameViewModel> WeeklySchedule { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }

    public WeeklyPicksViewModel(List<schedule> weeklySchedule, int userid)
    {
        List<GameViewModel> week = new List<GameViewModel>();
        foreach (var game in weeklySchedule)
        {
            GameViewModel g = new GameViewModel(game.away, game.home);
            week.Add(g);
        }
        WeeklySchedule = week;
    }
}


@model FootballPickEm.ViewModels.WeeklyPicksViewModel

<h2>Picks Page</h2>
<hr />

<div>
    <table>
        @foreach (var game in Model.WeeklySchedule) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => game.SelectedTeam, game.AwayTeam)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/@(game.AwayTeam.ToLower()).gif" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => game.AwayTeam)
                </td>
                <td>
                    AT
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => game.SelectedTeam, game.HomeTeam)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/images/@(game.HomeTeam.ToLower()).gif" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => game.HomeTeam)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: A `bool` property would not be appropriate (that's typically used with a checkbox). You need a property (say) `SelectedTeam` and 2 radio buttons - `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedTeam, Model.HomeTeam)` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedTeam, Model.AwayTeam)` and when you submit, `SelectedTeam` will contain the value of the selected team

Answer (score 1):

Good news.  You don't need to create 32 `bool`s.  You can just create one `string` (or `enum` or whatever else) that represents the team.  If you call the property `team`, you can generate radio buttons like this.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="team" value="piggers">The Piggers</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="team" value="dogcatchers">The Dogcatchers</label>
```

Then when you submit the form, your `team` property will contain a value like `"piggers"`.